# Can't figure out why carousel randomizer code randomly makes the carousel disappear on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, random

I have code that I'm using to make the BS carousel randomize the slides on page load, so that it will just pick one randomly and display it first. At first it was working great but now when I reload the page or try to hit it for the first time it doesn't display anything at all.

Here's the JQuery I'm using for it, I've tried to debugg it but I don't know JQuery very well

```
<!--code below is for carousel randomizer-->

<script>
    var $item = $('.carousel .item');
    $item.addClass('full-screen');

    var $numberofSlides = $('.item').length;
    var $currentSlide = Math.floor((Math.random() * $numberofSlides));

   $('.carousel-indicators li').each(function(){
   var $slideValue = $(this).attr('data-slide-to');
   if($currentSlide == $slideValue) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $item.eq($slideValue).addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $item.eq($slideValue).removeClass('active');
  }
});

$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 6000,
  pause: "false"
});
</script>
```

And here's the html to go with it

```
<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="item active">
        <img src="/images/banner1.jpg" alt="First Image">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/banner2.jpg" alt="Second Image">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/banner3.jpg" alt="Third Image">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/banner4.jpg" alt="Fourth Image">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/banner5.jpg" alt="Fifth Image">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="/images/banner6.jpg" alt="Sixth Image">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <!--<a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>-->
</div>
```

Is there anything noticeable that would cause it to just not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the script runs sometimes before jQuery is ready and throws an error instead.

You should put all of that code into jQuery's ready fonction

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Your code here
});
```

Or better yet, your code into it's own function to be called from the ready handler

```
<script>
    function InitCarousel(){
        var $item = $('.carousel .item');
        $item.addClass('full-screen');

        var $numberofSlides = $('.item').length;
        var $currentSlide = Math.floor((Math.random() * $numberofSlides));

        $('.carousel-indicators li').each(function(){
            var $slideValue = $(this).attr('data-slide-to');
            if($currentSlide == $slideValue) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $item.eq($slideValue).addClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $item.eq($slideValue).removeClass('active');
            }
        });

        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 6000,
            pause: "false"
        });
    }

    $(document).ready( InitCarousel );
</script>
```

Comment: Also, you did you mention what plugin / third party lib you use for the carousel. But I guess you used the one from [this site](https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-ui-carousel#heres-the-javascript). Their example shows that you need to put the code into jQuery's ready handler ;)